# Direction of Dependencies in Angular Modules

Tags: angular, module

What is the recommended approach and trade offs for splitting a large app into modules?

In particular, I would try to avoid circular dependencies, and I would try to ensure that components and services should be declared once in a single module only.

What is the effect if these practices are not followed?

If module A, the root module, imports modules B and C, and a service S is provided in both module B and C, would there be two instances of service S existing at runtime.

What would happens if module B provides one implementation of S whilst module C provides another implementation. Would that work, or would we have a last-in-wins situation where the first service registration gets overwritten by the second.

Comment: Those question you're having can be easily answered by builing a sample app to test the theories right? Some of them can be found here https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#shared-feature-module

Comment: I'd also recommend this: https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq and this: https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#what-if-i-import-the-same-module-twice

Answer (score 2):

As @HarryNinh and @DeborahK suggested, the official [docs](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule) is the best article I found about splitting your modules. This is just a prescribed way of splitting your modules and feel free to deviate from it if there is a need.
I have the same problem before and I ended up splitting the modules in this way. (This is heavily influenced from the official docs and from my own experience)

The **AppModule or root module** - This is the module that angular loads first. I try to make this as small as possible and import other modules from here such as SharedModule and CoreModule.

**Shared Module** - This module is where you put modules that you are going to need in a lot of places. For example if you often find that you always need to use FormsModule you put it here. Another example from my experience is that I lazy loaded some of my components as much as possible and I found myself repeating the imports like FormsModule. Another example is if you are using UI frameworks such as angular/material or ng-bootstrap, you should put it in SharedModule to prevent repeating the same imports from your lazy loaded modules. Feel free to import this from your FeatureModules. I know you might be wondering if there is a duplication of imports of modules. Well taken from official docs

> What if I import the same module twice?
>
> That's not a problem. When three modules all import Module 'A',
> Angular evaluates Module 'A' once, the first time it encounters it,
> and doesn't do so again.

**Core Module** -  This is where you put your providers for services that you need a single instance. Ideal candidate is if you have an **AuthService**, or some data service. This should **only** be imported once in your AppModule.

**Feature Module** - this is where you put your components and services with related functionalities. Usually you import this from your AppModule, but personally I tend not to because I want to lazy load as much as possible.

Hope this helps.